# Why does the `users` command return different users depending on whether I ssh or open a new terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, users, login, who

How does `users` define what users are logged in?

If I `ssh` into a box twice, I see my username twice listed if I execute `users`. However, if I create a new login shell via `sudo su -`, I do not see `root` listed as users. Same goes for any other user such as `sudo su - user`. Of course, a non-login shell also doesn't show up in `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`users` counts login sessions. From sudo:</strike>

> The su command is used to become another user *during* a login
>   session.

(Emphasis is mine.) A login session creates a new tty, where as `su` uses the existing tty.

I just looked at the source code to the *users* command. What it does is read [utmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp). So I guess the bottom line is that if you write a program and write to utmp, you'll be seen in users.

Comment: but what about `The -i (simulate initial login)` in `sudo -i`? I guess "simulate" is the key word here. Perhaps it's not really doing a login.

Comment: The key thing is allocating a tty. `-i` doesn't do that. It does run all the startup profiles the same as done after the tty is allocated.

Comment: weird. the tty makes it interactive, but can't you have a non-interactive login shell?

Comment: See recent edit.

Comment: Makes sense. There are lots of interactive non-login shells that don't show up from `users`

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to get at is that the `users` command does what it does: get information from a file. We can try to ascribe a rationale and reason to when things will write to that file, but in reality anything can do that not caring about conventions.

Comment: @rocky The key thing is writing to utmp. Opening a terminal emulator always allocates a tty, but often does not count as a login session for these purposes. Some terminal emulators are configurable to either write or not write it depending on how they're started.

Comment: Ok. I've modified the answer.